# Finding a rogue <!----> in PHP

Tags: php, html

This: `<!---->`

This... this... thing. Right there.

7 characters of evil, forcing IE to render all pages with it at the top like this in quirks mode:

```
<!----><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

If it's not evil I don't know what is, because it certainly isn't in my template file, since the first few lines of that are:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <?php $this->outputHead(); ?>
    </head>
```

I certainly don't see any issues in my actual outputting code:

```
function build()
{
    if ($this->disabled)
    {
        return $this->content;
    }
    else
    {
        global $footer;
        ob_start();
        $location = $this->location;
        include($this->location['theme_nr'].'/overall.php');
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}

function outputAll()
{
    // stop capturing everything
    $this->content = ob_get_clean();

    // build the page
    echo $this->build();
}
```

I really just don't get it. How could this *thing* get into my code?

I can just *imagine* that `>` bit at the end turning into a smile, and the thing is *laughing* at me.

It haunts my dreams, it kills my cats, I don't know what it's going to do next but it's going to kill *something*.

Help me, ye gods of web development!

**EDIT:** Just a note, it does appear in all browsers, but it seems to drive IE ballistic and none of the others.

Comment: Are you using some sort of framework?

Comment: What code is calling your functions?

Comment: trunk/index.php calls it on line 121

Comment: Is this only happening in IE, or is the comment there regardless of the browser?  If it's regardless (which I assume it is), the comment may be being echoed out separately before hand.

Comment: The comment is there regardless of the browser.

Answer (score 3):

I found the culprit.

Somehow, a kludge I have in a function to hide a MySQL error is only causing issues in one of my branches, even though the function and where it's called from hasn't changed between the two branches.

For those interested, the code in question:

```
function isexistinguser($uname,$pwd)
{
    global $location;

    $uname = mysql_real_escape_string($uname);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username = '$uname'");

    $hit = 0;
    $rowcounted = false;
    $salt = '';

    echo '<!--'; // cheap fix for mysql error - FIND A BETTER WAY!

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {       
        // Do stuff to figure out what to return
    }

    echo '-->'; // cheap fix for mysql error - FIND A BETTER WAY!

    return array($hit,$salt);
}
```

Comment: That's really funny. I also like how isexistinguser looks like extinguisher and...you probably already know what $hit looks like. :)

Comment: The physically appearance of $hit can vary depending on the $hit factory itself, or the parameters passed to the $hit factory prior to the job execution to create the $hit. Most commonly, it usually has a constant Color member of Color.SaddleBrown and has a bad code smell.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the git repo you posted and it is not contained within. You could try a diff from the copy on github to your current copy as the change is in the changes you made.

---

If you are using an IDE do a global file search for the string of characters. These kinda of "bugs" can be troublesome.

Comment: I'm using Notepad++... I don't think it has such a feature as it's pretty much just an extended Notepad as the name implies.

Comment: Notepad++ has no trouble searching for <!---->

Comment: I've tried searching manually for <!----> in a couple of files before giving up.

As for the git repo, it's up to date.

Comment: Notepad++ has the option of searching all open tabs (an option at the bottom of a normal CTRL+F search), so you can open a whole bunch of tabs and do one search through all of them.

Comment: Well. Nothing on my side. This is going to be nasty...

Comment: You should try searching <!-- instead of the whole thing.  I suspect it's dumping out <!--[some blank variable]-->, so the search wouldn't pick it up.

Comment: Time to switch. I'd recommend NetBeans with PHP module - works great.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a situation where grep would be handy, if you can use it either through cygwin or directly in Linux.  A quick example of just finding files with that HTML comment

```
grep -R "<\!---->" ./*
```

That should narrow the search.

Comment: Unfortunately I use Windows. As for Cygwin, well, the last time I tried to install it I stared at the download size and gave up. That was one or two years ago.

Comment: Aw well, thought something like that might be the case, but figured I'd throw it out there anyway.

Comment: Possibly not the simplest way, but you can get an account at http://silenceisdefeat.com/ (free Unix), upload your file using SFTP with something like Filezilla, then connect to it with Putty and run the command given above :D

Comment: get cygwin. It's about 10 youtube vids in size.

Answer (score 0):

About your error handling. The first way of dealing with it is to define and use your own handlers instead of php default ones with [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

As a simple fix, modify this line : `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username = '$uname'");`
with something like that :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username = '$uname'");
if(!$result || !is_resource($result){
  return array(0, '');
}
```

To end this, I recommend you check [PDO](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to use databases.

Comment: Actually, I found the error's derived from something completely different, and I'm now trying to figure out what's causing *that* issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845587/how-come-my-php-sessions-arent-carrying-across

Answer (score 0):

I would have looked for the 'evil' string:

`grep -R '\-\->' /your/folder`